# What logic solution should be done if I deleted a gameobject and now the gameobject is not exist but his data still exist and saved in a text file?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The script/s a bit long but all connected and I will explain where is the problem.

With this script SaveLoad I just save and load the data from text files using json.
The problem is at the Load method at line 97 :

```
var objectToSetState = uniqueIdToObject[saveObject.gameObjectUniqueID];
```

The variable uniqueIdToObject contains two items :

[image: Two items]

but the variable saveGame.saveObjects contains 3 items and each item have his own uniqueIdToObject:

[image: Three items]

When I'm using the Save method to save the data to a json file for example if I had on the hierarchy 3 objects with the GenerateGuid on them :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GenerateGuid : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string uniqueGuidID;

    private Guid guidID;
   
    public void GenerateGuidNum()
    {
        guidID = Guid.NewGuid();
        uniqueGuidID = guidID.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then in the json file I have data of three objects but then for example I deleted one of the objects from the hierarchy or removed from one of the object the script GenerateGuid then the SaveLoad script doesn't know I deleted anything and he read from the json file the whole data of three items but in fact there are only two items now or three items but one of them without the GenerateGuid on it.

The question is what should I do in that case ? Should I update somehow the json file when the user delete or change on the hierarchy one of the objects ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SaveLoad : MonoBehaviour
{
    public FadeInOutSaveGameText fadeInOutSaveGame;
    public float timeToStartSaving;
    public float savingFadeInOutTime;

    private List<GameObject> objectsToSave;
    private string saveString;

    private void Awake()
    {
        SaveSystem.Init();

        if (objectsToSave == null)
        {
            objectsToSave = new List<GameObject>();
        }

        Debug.Log("Start");

        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToSave.Count; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log($"{i}");
            Debug.Log($"{objectsToSave[i].name}");
        }

        Debug.Log("End Init");
    }

    public void Save(string Folder, string FileName)
    {
        UpdateObjectsToSave();

        SaveGame saveGame = new SaveGame();
        saveGame.saveObjects = new List<SaveObject>();
        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToSave.Count; i++)
        {
            SaveObject saveObject = new SaveObject();
            saveObject.transformSaver = new TransformSaver();
            Debug.Log($"{i}");
            Debug.Log($"{objectsToSave[i].name}");
            saveObject.gameObjectUniqueID = objectsToSave[i].GetComponent<GenerateGuid>().uniqueGuidID;
            var x = objectsToSave[i].GetComponents<Component>();
            var stateQueryComponent = x.Where(component => component is IStateQuery).ToList();
            List<KeyToValue> componentsState = new List<KeyToValue>();
            foreach (var z in stateQueryComponent)
            {
                var w = z as IStateQuery;
                componentsState.Add(new KeyToValue(w.UniqueId.ToString(), w.GetState()));
            }

            saveObject.transformSaver.position = objectsToSave[i].transform.position;
            saveObject.transformSaver.rotation = objectsToSave[i].transform.rotation;
            saveObject.transformSaver.scaling = objectsToSave[i].transform.localScale;

            saveObject.componentsState = componentsState;
            saveGame.saveObjects.Add(saveObject);
        }

        string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(saveGame);

        if (Folder == null && FileName == null)
        {
            SaveSystem.Save(json);
        }
        else
        {
            SaveSystem.Save(Folder, FileName, json);
        }
    }

    public void Load(string Folder, string FileName)
    {
        UpdateObjectsToSave();

        Dictionary<string, GameObject> uniqueIdToObject = objectsToSave
            .ToDictionary(o => o.GetComponent<GenerateGuid>().uniqueGuidID, o => o);

        saveString = SaveSystem.Load(Folder, FileName);

        if (saveString != null)
        {
            SaveGame saveGame = JsonUtility.FromJson<SaveGame>(saveString);
            foreach (var saveObject in saveGame.saveObjects)
            {
                List<KeyToValue> loadedComponents = saveObject.componentsState;
                var objectToSetState = uniqueIdToObject[saveObject.gameObjectUniqueID];

                objectToSetState.transform.position = saveObject.transformSaver.position;
                objectToSetState.transform.rotation = saveObject.transformSaver.rotation;
                objectToSetState.transform.localScale = saveObject.transformSaver.scaling;

                var y = objectToSetState.GetComponents<Component>();
                var z = y.Where(component => component is IStateQuery).ToList();
                Dictionary<string, IStateQuery> zz = z.ToDictionary(sq => (sq as IStateQuery).UniqueId.ToString(), sq => sq as IStateQuery);

                foreach (KeyToValue keyvalue in loadedComponents)
                {
                    zz[keyvalue.Key].SetState(keyvalue.Value);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void UpdateObjectsToSave()
    {
        var objectsWithGenerateGuid = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<GenerateGuid>().ToList();
        objectsToSave = new List<GameObject>();
        if (objectsWithGenerateGuid.Count > 0 && objectsToSave.Count == 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < objectsWithGenerateGuid.Count; i++)
            {
                objectsToSave.Add(objectsWithGenerateGuid[i].gameObject);
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator AuatomaticSaveWithTime()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeToStartSaving);

        Save(null, null);

        StartCoroutine(fadeInOutSaveGame.OverAllTime(savingFadeInOutTime));
    }

    public IEnumerator SaveWithTime(string Folder, string FileName)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeToStartSaving);

        Save(Folder, FileName);

        StartCoroutine(fadeInOutSaveGame.OverAllTime(savingFadeInOutTime));
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to update the data file the moment the component gets removed?  If the removal is based on user interaction, i would removed the entry the moment the request to remove the object/component happens (since you still have an id to use to lookup the entry).

Comment: @hijinxbassist Is there a way to monitoring changes in the hierarchy in real-time and update the saved game file? if I deleted an object in the hierarchy how can I update the file what will trigger the change in the hierarchy?

Comment: Is this happening from the editor?

Comment: You can probably catch the removal from OnDestroy of the component.  You can wrap that in a conditional compilation block for editor as well to avoid the change happening at runtime.

Comment: I was wondering that as well.  Since you are saving the current state, the previous should be discarded right?

Answer (score 0):

Solution : To check if the key exist :

```
if (uniqueIdToObject.ContainsKey(saveObject.gameObjectUniqueID))
```

It's not updating the JSON file on the hard disk and if the user will edit the file with notepad he, right gets confused because the data on the file still contains the non exist key/s but in the code, it's working fine.

but I'm guessing that the user in most of the time if at all will not edit the saved games files on the hard disk so it's not that bad. maybe the problem will be later with some space or the file size if some non existing data will still be written but for now, I think this is a good enough solution.

```
public void Load(string Folder, string FileName)
    {
       //var a =  UpdateObjectsToSave();

        Dictionary<string, GameObject> uniqueIdToObject = objectsToSave
            .ToDictionary(o => o.GetComponent<GenerateGuid>().uniqueGuidID, o => o);

        saveString = SaveSystem.Load(Folder, FileName);

        if (saveString != null)
        {
            SaveGame saveGame = JsonUtility.FromJson<SaveGame>(saveString);
            foreach (var saveObject in saveGame.saveObjects)
            {
                List<KeyToValue> loadedComponents = saveObject.componentsState;

                if (uniqueIdToObject.ContainsKey(saveObject.gameObjectUniqueID))
                {
                    var objectToSetState = uniqueIdToObject[saveObject.gameObjectUniqueID];

                    objectToSetState.transform.position = saveObject.transformSaver.position;
                    objectToSetState.transform.rotation = saveObject.transformSaver.rotation;
                    objectToSetState.transform.localScale = saveObject.transformSaver.scaling;

                    var y = objectToSetState.GetComponents<Component>();
                    var z = y.Where(component => component is IStateQuery).ToList();
                    Dictionary<string, IStateQuery> zz = z.ToDictionary(sq => (sq as IStateQuery).UniqueId.ToString(), sq => sq as IStateQuery);

                    foreach (KeyToValue keyvalue in loadedComponents)
                    {
                        zz[keyvalue.Key].SetState(keyvalue.Value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```